# Expectation of excess demand

Tags: probability, expectation

Suppose random variable D has C.D.F. F.
D is demand and y is supply in this case.
Now, excess demand (D-y), D>y is lost and excess inventory (y-D), y>D is wasted.
I have to find Expectation of lost demand, ie E(D-y) given D>y.

What I have is 
$$E(D-y)^{+}=\int_{y}^{\infty }xdF(x)-y(1-F(y)),$$ 
but I'm not able to work my way through. Detailed description will be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Was the expression of the expectation given to you (do you have to use it) or did you think of that yourself?

Comment: OK so far, but You have not yet taken into account the condition D>y.

Comment: is supply y just some constant number

Comment: The expression is taken from the paper "The Competitive Newsboy" by Steven A. Lippman and Kevin F. McCardle. http://www.jstor.org/stable/171925?seq=2

Answer (score 0):

It may be better look at this in the perspective of a conditional expectation since you want to know expected demand given that it is in excess (i.e. expected excess demand) stated as $E(D|D>y)$ now this relies on finding what $P(D\leq t|D>y)$ looks like which would be 
$$F_{D|D>y}=P(D\leq t|D>y)=\frac{\int_{y}^{t}f(x)dx}{\int_{y}^{\infty}f(x)dx}=$$
Thus pdf for $D|D>y$ is merely
$$f_{D|D>y}(x)=\frac{1}{\int_{y}^{\infty}f(x)dx}f(x)\textrm{ for }x>y$$
Thus expected excess demand would be (i represent demand by x instead of d to avoid confusion)
$$E(D|D>y)=\frac{1}{\int_{y}^{\infty}f(x)dx}\int_{y}^{\infty}xf(x)dx$$

Note: I worked this up kind of late so if anyone has any corrections or comments please do so